# Adding newly created objects into a vector inside the object?

Tags: c++

Would some thing like this work?

```
RawModel::RawModel(GLuint vao, GLsizei count)
    : m_VAO(vao), m_Count(count)
{
    m_RawModels.push_back(this);
}

RawModel::~RawModel()
{
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < m_RawModels.size(); i++)
        delete m_RawModels[i];
}
```

I am fairly new to the language and I don't know if it would work.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? The code you submit would give an undefined behaviour (it would probably crash). `delete this;` is extremely weird, even more so if done _within_ the destructor. Just don't do this.

Comment: And this kind of programming question should be posted on [so] because it's not specifically related to game development.

Comment: While 'delete this' is in the general sense not prohibited, there are situations wherein it's a [bad idea](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this). What you've shown in your code is almost certainly a bad idea; you can't ensure RawModel was allocated with new, and even if was you'd be double-deleting it.